# Ruby vs. Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the difference between Ruby on Rails and Ruby? I have asked four people but none can come up with a definitive answer. Is Rails a library of sorts for Ruby, a la Django to Python or Cocoa to Objective C, or is it a totally different language with different capabilities?
What can one do on Rails that cannot be done just with ruby?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Ruby and ROR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999143/what-is-the-difference-between-ruby-and-ror)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rails is a framework for building web applications with Ruby.  Ruby is a general purpose programming language.  Yes, Rails is analogous to Django.

Comment: it would be good if Rails' usefulness can be shown through some small example +1

Comment: One of the major things that Rails does is force an MVC pattern for your web app. You can read about it on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/. As an example of Rails' focus on web development it provides a myriad of helpers.`mail_to('admin@stackoverflow.com')` will generate a mailto link: `<a href="mailto: admin@stackoverflow.com">admin@stackoverflow.com</a>`.

Comment: Yes, great suggestion to explore the Rails sites (main site and guides) to get started.  Though getting into discussions about the MVC pattern is probably a bit beyond someone just discovering the difference between Ruby and Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is a programming lang like python and obj C. Rails is not a programming lang. It is a web framework for creating web apps and uses Ruby programming lang. :)

Answer (score 0):

RoR is Web application framework on Ruby. Read more in Official Rails Documentation [here](http://rubyonrails.org/)