# What is the difference between Ruby and ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Couldn't understand the difference between Ruby and ROR. For what purpose they both are used. Could somebody please explain.

Comment: Yeah.. that looks duplicate but when I tried searching for it on stackoverflow it didn't showed me those questions. How did you guys find it?

Comment: @user3521293 I found out [like that](http://bit.ly/1eeBRzX). (I'm just messing around. Welcome to stackoverflow !)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby is a [programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language) and Ruby on Rails is a [web framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework).

Possible use cases for ruby:

- [A package manager](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew)
- [A tool for building and distributing working environments (Vagrant)](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant)
- [A css preprocessor](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)

Possible use cases for rails:

- [Mostly](https://github.com/discourse/discourse)
- [Websites](https://github.com/)